# Limit row results conditionally

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I need to add in some conditional logic into a query where if a row has the same `BUSINESS_UNIT` and `VOUCHER_ID` then to output only the row where the `WTHD_RULE` is equal to 'PA1' I can't apply the criteria (`WTHD_RULE = 'PA1')` universally (to the entire query) as I still want to get rows not containing `WTHD_RULE = 'PA1'. I just want to filter the results using this criteria when there are rows with the same`BUSINESS_UNIT`and`VOUCHER_ID`.

Essentially what is happening is that there are two payments being applied to the same voucher/business unit but I don't want the additional row (where there are duplicates) if it does not contain 'PA1' for `WTHD_RULE`

[image]

Results would include data from the first query as well as the 2nd row in the 2nd query. Is there a way to accomplish this without using a CTE?

**EDIT:**

Alternatively is there a way to so a self join and create a new column for `WTHD_AMT` where the WTHD_RULE is equal to 'PA1' ?

**EDIT 2:**

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   BUSINESS_UNIT   INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,VOUCHER_ID      INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,PYMNT_CNT       INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,PYMNT_ID        INTEGER 
  ,PYMNT_TYPE      VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
  ,PAID_AMT        NUMERIC(7,3) NOT NULL
  ,PYMNT_GROSS_AMT NUMERIC(8,3) NOT NULL
  ,DUE_DT          DATE  NOT NULL
  ,PRIMARY KEY(BUSINESS_UNIT,VOUCHER_ID)
);
INSERT INTO mytable(BUSINESS_UNIT,VOUCHER_ID,PYMNT_CNT,PYMNT_ID,PYMNT_TYPE,PAID_AMT,PYMNT_GROSS_AMT,DUE_DT) VALUES (50000,00026130,2,NULL,'W',0.000,30.700,'2018-06-29 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO mytable(BUSINESS_UNIT,VOUCHER_ID,PYMNT_CNT,PYMNT_ID,PYMNT_TYPE,PAID_AMT,PYMNT_GROSS_AMT,DUE_DT) VALUES (50000,00026130,1,0000121315,'R',969.300,969.300,'2018-06-29 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO mytable(BUSINESS_UNIT,VOUCHER_ID,PYMNT_CNT,PYMNT_ID,PYMNT_TYPE,PAID_AMT,PYMNT_GROSS_AMT,DUE_DT) VALUES (50000,00026131,1,NULL,'R',0.000,0.000,'2018-06-30 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO mytable(BUSINESS_UNIT,VOUCHER_ID,PYMNT_CNT,PYMNT_ID,PYMNT_TYPE,PAID_AMT,PYMNT_GROSS_AMT,DUE_DT) VALUES (50000,00026132,1,NULL,'R',0.000,1000.000,'2010-06-30 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO mytable(BUSINESS_UNIT,VOUCHER_ID,PYMNT_CNT,PYMNT_ID,PYMNT_TYPE,PAID_AMT,PYMNT_GROSS_AMT,DUE_DT) VALUES (50000,00026133,1,0000121312,'R',100.000,100.000,'2018-06-28 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO mytable(BUSINESS_UNIT,VOUCHER_ID,PYMNT_CNT,PYMNT_ID,PYMNT_TYPE,PAID_AMT,PYMNT_GROSS_AMT,DUE_DT) VALUES (50000,00026134,1,0000121309,'R',100.000,100.000,'2018-06-28 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO mytable(BUSINESS_UNIT,VOUCHER_ID,PYMNT_CNT,PYMNT_ID,PYMNT_TYPE,PAID_AMT,PYMNT_GROSS_AMT,DUE_DT) VALUES (50000,00026135,1,0000121308,'R',100.000,100.000,'2018-08-02 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO mytable(BUSINESS_UNIT,VOUCHER_ID,PYMNT_CNT,PYMNT_ID,PYMNT_TYPE,PAID_AMT,PYMNT_GROSS_AMT,DUE_DT) VALUES (50000,00026136,2,NULL,'W',0.000,3.070,'2018-08-24 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO mytable(BUSINESS_UNIT,VOUCHER_ID,PYMNT_CNT,PYMNT_ID,PYMNT_TYPE,PAID_AMT,PYMNT_GROSS_AMT,DUE_DT) VALUES (50000,00026136,1,0000121314,'R',96.930,96.930,'2018-08-24 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO mytable(BUSINESS_UNIT,VOUCHER_ID,PYMNT_CNT,PYMNT_ID,PYMNT_TYPE,PAID_AMT,PYMNT_GROSS_AMT,DUE_DT) VALUES (50000,00026137,2,NULL,'W',0.000,30.700,'2018-09-04 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO mytable(BUSINESS_UNIT,VOUCHER_ID,PYMNT_CNT,PYMNT_ID,PYMNT_TYPE,PAID_AMT,PYMNT_GROSS_AMT,DUE_DT) VALUES (50000,00026137,1,0000121316,'R',969.300,969.300,'2018-09-04 00:00:00.000');
```

With this sample/schema my desired output would be like this:

```
BUSINESS_UNIT   VOUCHER_ID  PYMNT_CNT   PYMNT_ID    PYMNT_TYPE  PAID_AMT    PYMNT_GROSS_AMT DUE_DT
50000           26130       1           121315      R           969.3 969.3 6/29/2018
50000           26131       1                       R           0   0   6/30/2018
50000           26132       1                       R           0   1000    6/30/2010
50000           26133       1           121312      R           100 100 6/28/2018
50000           26134       1           121309      R           100 100 6/28/2018
50000           26135       1           121308      R           100 100 8/2/2018
50000           26136       1           121314      R           96.93   96.93   8/24/2018
50000           26137       1           121316      R           969.3   969.3   9/4/2018
```

Formatted better below: 
[image]

Comment: Don't understand.  On the one hand you want "I still want to get rows not containing this." on the other you want " I just want to filter the results using this criteria" .  These are in conflict.  Please post some sample data (not a screenshot) and desired results.

Comment: update your question and add  your query as text too  ..

Comment: @user1443098 I edited the post, hopefully it makes more sense. Essentially I'm trying to remove the duplicates in the above example, preserving the row that contains `WTHD_RULE = 'PA1'` and not filter out other data that contains other values for `WTHD_RULE` (that aren't duplicated)

Comment: So,  could you please post some data and expected results? like this: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @user1443098 I added a data schema and sample expected results

Comment: You can see in the expected results where the 3 rows would be filtered out

Comment: Your sample data has duplicate keys.  Can you change those so that the insert statements work?  also I don't see a column called WTHD_RULE

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You want all the table plus some rows from that table. How on earth you'd differentiate rows?

Comment: Your explanation and data don't match. You are showing multiple records per `BUSINESS_UNIT` and `VOUCHER_ID`, but your `CREATE TABLE` statement makes them the primary key (i.e. no duplicates possible). You are talking about  `WTHD_RULE`, but you table doesn't contain such column. Then: what combinations are possible? One row with `WTHD_RULE = 'PA1'` only? One row with `WTHD_RULE = 'PA1'` and several other rows? No rows with `WTHD_RULE = 'PA1'` but several other rows? Two rows with `WTHD_RULE = 'PA1'` and several other rows? … Which rows do you want to select in which situation?

Answer (score 0):

You removed `WTHD_RULE` from the sample data... but if it existed you'd use a window function to do this. Also, in your sample data, your `PRIMARY KEY` is invalid since PK's can't contain duplicates.

```
select
*
FROM(    
    select 
        *
        ,RN = row_number() over (partition by BUSINESS_UNIT, VOUCHER_ID order by case when WTHD_RULE = 'PA1' then 1 else 2 end)
    from
        myTable
    ) x
where x.RN = 1
```